# How do I reference a dll from a different subfolder in my .exe directory

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can make my winform app referance dll's be utilized while it is not in the same folder as my .exe file.

I have tried editing my app config file and tried adding 
`<probing privatePath="Bin"/>` Yet still no luck.

```
<probing privatePath="Bin"/>
```

I want my win forms app to run without having the dlls in the same directory.

Comment: Is that `Bin` folder with the DLL's in the same folder as the EXE?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but the ```"Bin"``` is a place holder for now... I will rename it later

Comment: So is the folder with your DLL's a subfolder of where your EXE is?

Comment: yes my dlls are in a subfolder

Comment: I don't know then. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) do say it should work. What error message are you getting? Does the error message change if you remove the `probing` element?

Comment: I am going to test again now to find out for you one second .

Comment: Ok so the dlls still are put into directory with the .exe files in it

Comment: Ok i figured it out. The dll's stayed in the .exe directory because they were a refence in my solution explorer

Comment: Thank you for your time.